# How to open a different form depending on which user is currently logged in

Tags: vb.net

I have two forms Tutor Registration form and Student Registration form?
I would like to know how in vb.net i can save the values in the same table and hereafter differentiate them based on their roles?

Comment: Could you use a column for role in the registration table?

Comment: Can you post some sample code for what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

See [`Environment.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get which user is currently logged in.

Comment: I read somewhere before that Environment.Username can be spoofed.  I cannot seem to find that source and seeing as it is maybe a homework question, it may not be a big deal.  Just thought I would throw it out there to see what others think...

Comment: @JasonBayldon Are you confused with `My.User.Name`?

Comment: No, it was definitely environment.username, I believe it was implied that somehow you could alter the memory the variable is stored..

Answer (score -1):

my sugestion is turn your startup form into a splash screen with a timer , check the username and open the form you want wen the timer ticks